# What is the strategy of query evaluation in DBMS when Limit is used in query?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-recommendation

I have following tables in database

```
post(post_id , user_id , post_text , parsed_text) ;
Comment(comment_id , post_id , user_id , comment_text) ;
friend(id , user_id , friend_id ) ;
group (id , user_id ,group_id ) ;
like  (id, user_id , page_id ) ;
```

SQL to retrieve data from posts

```
 $posts =  mysql_query("select * from post where user_id in 
(select f_id  from ((select friend_id as f_id from friend  where user_id = 'a') 
union (select group_id as f_id  from group  where user_id = 'a') 
union (select page_id as f_id   where user_id = 'a'  ))) order by post_id limit 0 , 30");
```

In these table there are BTREE index on post_id in post table , comment_id in comment table and  id in like , friend , share table ?

How DBMS evaluates this query to get 30 rows .

Is there any way to retrieve data from database from bottom  of the table ? Bottom in the sense id is auto increment so i need to retrieve data from database as

```
If table has id 'N' then it should start retrieving data as 
first 'n-1' th'tupple ,second  'n-2' th tupple ,third 'n-3' th tupple and so on 
without using 'ORDER BY' .
```

This can reduce time complexity for above query .

Comment: Why do you believe that avoiding 'ORDER BY' will reduce time complexity?

Comment: If i use ORDER BY   than the DBMS may sort data before output ?

Comment: You can't have the 30 highest IDs in the result without using `ORDER BY`. But the query seems to have other issues as well (besides efficiency). You are joining `user_id` with `group_id` and `page_id` ...?

Comment: The query results may need to be sorted. But you may have an index (or could create an index) that would make the sort trivial.  If you write your own process then think about the overhead of doing it yourself and dealing with all the possible stumbling blocks.

Comment: @ypercube i took union of all keys than i joined .

Comment: Yeah but you union group_id from one table with page_id from another and friend_id from a third. This makes no sense.

Comment: @RLF If above QUERY  returns 10,000 tupples when there is no limit . We need atmost 30 tupples out of them in ORDER BY ID , so how to make it efficient so that this returns atmost 30 returns without overhead of large no of tupples  ?

Comment: @ypercube yeah ,  i can create only one table for friend , like , group . Due to large no of entries in one table , table become too large , so i thought why not decrease length of table and take union of all and take join of these keys with posts .

Comment: @user3610792 I am mystified. If you have a large number of tupples, you have to deal with them somehow.  How do you know which are the newest rows unless you 'look at them' in the code?

Comment: I believe the point @ypercube is trying to make is that you are mixing groups, pages, likes in the same column, even though they are absolutely different entities. *That* is what makes no sense.

Comment: @Andry Actually i need only id to retrieve Posts of them  , so i took union of them .

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying down to the `post` table, for discussion.

Create a unique index on the `post_id`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX recent_post_id ON post(post_id)
```

Then query the data as such:

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
WHERE user_id IN (your criteria) 
ORDER BY post_id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Of course, the most overhead may well be your nested collection of rows that you UNION together to get the criteria for recent posts.

Comment: I already created  index on post_id as i mentioned in the question .

Comment: So you did, though you did not specify `unique`. The main point here was `ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 30`. This gives extra information to the optimizer which may result in a better execution plan.

Comment: Also **post_id is primary key** for table.